# applying javascript with a default value

Tags: javascript

I use this javascript `onkeypress="return autoMask(this,event, '####-####');"`

```
<input type="text" name="tel_dom" maxlength="10" 
       onkeypress="return autoMask(this,event, '####-####');" 
       value="<?php echo $row['telefono_dom']; ?>">
```

If I want to add a default value to the input, why the script doesn't format the default value?

I always have to press a key to format the string. How this problem can be solved?

Comment: becuase this is what you say to javascript to do. note the `onkeypress` attribute.

Comment: How do you add a "default value"?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript the onkeypress="" will only be triggered by a keypress. If you want to trigger it automatically, once the tag is loaded, use the onload="" attribute.
As soon as the element is loaded it will try to execute whatever is specified in the onload attribute.